# How to ADD IF ELSE IF in MYSQL Stored Procedures WHERE CLAUSE to not run the AND inside WHERE when the parameter is NULL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE filing_route(IN appl_name varchar(500),
IN granted char(1),
IN oppose tinyint(4),
IN beginDate date,
IN endDate date,
IN ipc varchar(300))
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS total_company_applications;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS family_aggregate;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_filing_route;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_filing_route2;

IF (granted IS NOT NULL AND oppose IS NOT NULL AND beginDate IS NOT NULL AND endDate IS NOT NULL AND ipc IS NOT NULL) THEN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS total_company_applications AS
    (SELECT distinct a.appln_id FROM sample.tls201_appln a
    INNER JOIN sample.tls207_pers_appln b ON b.appln_id = a.appln_id
    INNER JOIN sample.tls906_person c ON c.person_id = b.person_id
    INNER JOIN sample.tls209_appln_ipc d ON d.appln_id = a.appln_id
    WHERE c.psn_name LIKE CONCAT(appl_name, '%')
    AND a.granted LIKE granted
    AND a.isOpposed = oppose
    AND a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN beginDate and endDate
    AND FIND_IN_SET(d.ipc_class_symbol, ipc));
ELSE IF(oppose IS NOT NULL AND beginDate IS NOT NULL AND endDate IS NOT NULL AND ipc IS NOT NULL) THEN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS total_company_applications AS
    (SELECT distinct a.appln_id FROM sample.tls201_appln a
    INNER JOIN sample.tls207_pers_appln b ON b.appln_id = a.appln_id
    INNER JOIN sample.tls906_person c ON c.person_id = b.person_id
    INNER JOIN sample.tls209_appln_ipc d ON d.appln_id = a.appln_id
    WHERE c.psn_name LIKE CONCAT(appl_name, '%')
    AND a.granted LIKE granted
    AND a.isOpposed = oppose
    AND a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN beginDate and endDate
    AND FIND_IN_SET(d.ipc_class_symbol, ipc));

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS family_aggregate AS 
(SELECT b.docdb_family_id, b.appln_auth, b.receiving_office, MIN(b.appln_filing_date) as first_date 
FROM total_company_applications a
INNER JOIN tls201_appln b ON b.appln_id = a.appln_id 
WHERE b.appln_filing_year < 9999
GROUP BY b.docdb_family_id, b.appln_auth, b.receiving_office
ORDER BY b.docdb_family_id, first_date);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_filing_route AS (
SELECT docdb_family_id, first_date, group_concat(distinct appln_auth, IF(appln_auth = 'WO', CONCAT(' (RO = ', receiving_office, ')'), '') ORDER BY appln_auth DESC separator ', ') as filing_route 
FROM family_aggregate
GROUP BY docdb_family_id, first_date);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_filing_route2 AS (
SELECT docdb_family_id, group_concat(filing_route ORDER BY first_date separator ' -> ') as filing_route
FROM tmp_filing_route
GROUP BY docdb_family_id);

SELECT filing_route, COUNT(distinct docdb_family_id) as num_families
FROM tmp_filing_route2
GROUP BY filing_route
ORDER BY num_families DESC
LIMIT 20;


END$
```

I have a stored procedure filing_route I don't want to run the line with AND and the parameter Where if the parameter is null.
I tried this

```
WHERE c.psn_name LIKE CONCAT(appl_name, '%')
IF(granted IS NOT NULL)
    AND a.granted LIKE granted
END IF
AND a.isOpposed = oppose
```

But it is not working. Can I get suggestions for how to make default cases if the parameter is not given or null. If I do the previous workaround that is make combination for all the 5 cases. I have to build 2^5=64 cases to check.Is there a smarter way to do this.

Comment: You are missing 2 end ifs.

Comment: No I want to know that how can I add AND only if the parameter exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question

> No I want to know that how can I add AND only if the parameter exists

You can try with below,just use `IF()`,the key point is when the condition not match just add `1=1` to make the sql syntax correct

```
WHERE c.psn_name LIKE CONCAT(appl_name, '%')
  AND a.isOpposed = oppose
  AND IF(granted IS NOT NULL,a.granted LIKE granted,1=1)
```

Comment: @HarshdeepKanhai Glad to help you!